# How to handle multiple exceptions using JAXB and xsd

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb

I'm trying to parse the xml file. Before parsing, I'm trying to validate the xml file. I have used SchemaFactory to handle the exceptions using xsd file.

```
 SchemaFactory sf = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI); 
Schema schema = sf.newSchema(new File("customer.xsd")); 
jaxbunmarshaller.setSchema(schema);
```

I'm able to catch only one exception at a time while validating xml file. But how can I catch multiple exceptions of an entire xml file at once while validating xml file using xsd.

Can anyone please help me out regarding this issue ...

Comment: Can we use any ErrorHandlers for this ?